# MongoDB Aggregate Framework - Group by Year

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I've been trying to use the aggregate function to group date fields by year:

```
db.identities.aggregate([
{
    $group : {
        _id : { year : {$year : "$birth_date"}},
        total : {$sum : 1}
        }
    }   
])
```

Some of my dates however fall before 1970 and being a Windows user I get a nasty error about gmtime:

```
{
    "errmsg" : "exception: gmtime failed - your system doesn't support dates before 1970",
    "code" : 16422,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

I know the obvious answer now is for me to get a virtual machine running or something but I was just curious if there were any work-arounds for windows (Windows 7 in my case). Failing that how much of a performance hit would storing the date as a nested object be i.e:

```
birth_date : {
  year : 1980,
  month : 12,
  day : 9
}
```

I'm not too sure how hectic that would be with indexes etc.

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: what version of Mongo are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some versions of Windows have been known to work. By any chance, are you using a 32-bit OS? The code in question is [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/07e2bbe7293ec7fda7858f141da218477c255f1e#L2R660), and depends upon the `gmtime_s()` implementation.

If this collection is simply for aggregation queries, you can certainly get by with storing date components in an object. I'd suggest abbreviating the field names (e.g. `y`, `m`, `d`) to save on storage, since the field strings are present in each stored document. The trade-off here is that none of the aggregation date operators can be used. You may want to store the timestamp as a signed integer (e.g. `ts`) so that you can easily do range queries if necessary.

Comment: apologies for the long delay - only just re-visited this one. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: This is somewhat diabolical as it does seriously cripple the `date type` implementation on this platform. This occurs on 64-bit build as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21869602/2313887

Comment: @NeilLunn: I noted your comment in the other question and opened [SERVER-12816](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12816) to track this.

Comment: I find this discouraging that this has been an issue for 3 years and it is only considered an enhancement. In v3.0.3 on Windows Server 2012 R2, it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by the minimum date not being handled well when aggregated.

A quick workaround (if possible) is to filter the date, either through the ff:

- Remove the rows with minimum date (via match / filter)
- Filter through a certain date (greater than x date)

Then aggregate.