# Problems with dates in MongoDB / Windows 10

Tags: javascript, mongodb, windows-10

I'm having a weird issue with MongoDB in Windows 10. I've migrated a database that's working perfectly fine in MacOS and Linux to a Windows 10 machine.

Same mongodb version : 3.4.7

The issue seems to be related to one that other people experienced but it's not exactly the same ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869602/mongodb-date-issue-when-before-1970) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903687/mongodb-aggregate-framework-group-by-year))

I get an error saying "gmtime failed - your system doesn't support dates before 1970" when I call a view that uses $dateToString in the projection.

And I also get only 101 records if I call the same view via Robo 3T.

But the difference in my case is that I don't have dates before 1970 in this particular collection.

So I ran this code on Robo 3T to try something, and I can't understand the result:

```
db.getCollection('vehicles').find({}).forEach(function(vehicle){
   var date = new Date(vehicle.dates.entry);
   print(date);
   print(date.getYear());   
})
```

This is the result for one record:

```
Fri Oct 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)
115
```

So the date seems to be constructed properly but the getYear() returns 115 instead of 2015.

The same code on MacOS or Linux works as expected.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: That's a JavaScript thing. You mean `date.getFullYear()`

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn that might be the case but even if it is it's a mongo thing. The code I wrote was just a test to try this out, because I don't have dates prior to 1970 in this collection. I did try the getFullYear and it works. but I still have the same problem. I'll edit the question to remove that assumption.

Comment: Edit the question why? This is how the code for a JavaScript `Date` works. There is no other answer. You simply use `.getFullYear()` and not `.getYear()`. It's not that hard to work out. Your "edit" is a **different question** So I'm rolling it back to what you originally asked. If you have a new question the [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) Instead.

Comment: See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12816 as well